# Laravel 7 General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: laravel, reference, migration

I've been researching this for hours, can't seem to solve it. Here is the error

`General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table 'users' add constraint 'users_discord_id_foreign' foreign key ('discord_id') references 'discord_o_auths' ('id'))`

Here is my DiscordOAuths Migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('discord_o_auths', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        $table->integer('id')->unique();
        $table->string('access_token')->unique();
        $table->string('refresh_token')->unique();
        $table->bigInteger('token_expiration');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And here is my Users Migration.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        $table->id();
        $table->boolean('admin')->default(false);
        $table->integer('color_scheme')->default(0);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        $table->integer('discord_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('discord_id')->references('id')->on('discord_o_auths');
    });
}
```

The DiscordOAuths table is created before the Users table as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `discord_o_auths.id` isn't unsigned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign a foreign key constraint to an `integer` column, which is not the same as the `unsigned` columns that Laravel uses for its id's.

In your `DiscordOAuths` you have to replace `$table->integer('id')->unique();` with `$table->bigIncrements('id');` or the new method added in Laravel 7 `$table->id();` which is an alias of the previous one.

Your `discord_id` column in the `users` migration also needs to be an unsigned column. You have to define it using either `$table->unsignedBigInteger('discord_id');` or its alias that came with Laravel 7: `$table->foreignId('discord_id');`

So your migrations would look like this:

For `DiscordOAuths`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('discord_o_auths', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        $table->id();
        $table->string('access_token')->unique();
        $table->string('refresh_token')->unique();
        $table->bigInteger('token_expiration');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And for `users` it would be like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        $table->id();
        $table->boolean('admin')->default(false);
        $table->integer('color_scheme')->default(0);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        $table->foreignId('discord_id');
        $table->foreign('discord_id')->references('id')->on('discord_o_auths');
    });
}
```